How do you add a keyway to a cylinder inner diameter?
How do you add a keyway to a cylinder inner diameter?



You should describe your problem in the body of the question and fix the image links. You could provide details about what you have tried as far and why it did not work for you as well as some context.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Select a few inner faces close to any axis, for example X. Then extrude along the X-axis (press E for Extrude then X to choose the X-axis). For new faces you must apply X-axis alignment (S>X>0>Enter)

There is no logical need to use any particular axis. It can be extruded in any direction.
